# Is there a way to refer to the current selected text in a command in Vim?

Tags: vim

Say in my C head file  I wanna include another file which has not being created yet:

```
#include "AnotherFile.h" /*not being created yet*/
```

Now, I select the file in Visual Mode, 
      #include "`AnotherFile.h`"

How to  create a new file with the name of what I've selected? I mean,

```
:e  {something that  refers to what I selected}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest I can think of is to create a function:

```
function! W() range
  execute "e " .  getline("'<")[getpos("'<")[2]-1:getpos("'>")[2]] 
endfu
```

You can then select the word and type `:call W()` + enter, which should open the new buffer.

**EDIT** The function above does not work without errors if the buffer containing the `#include` is modified. In such case, the following function is suited better:

```
function! W() range
  let l:fileName = getline("'<")[getpos("'<")[2]-1:getpos("'>")[2]] 
  new      
  execute "w " . l:fileName
endfu
```

**EDIT 2** You can also try to type `:e <cfile>` (see `:help <cfile>`).

**EDIT 3** Finally, under `:help gf` you find hidden

```
If you do want to edit a new file, use: >
        :e <cfile>
To make gf always work like that: 
        :map gf :e <cfile><CR>
```

Comment: EDIT2 above seems like the correct answer, no need for a function.  `:e <cfile>` works when cursor is on the filename, regardless of whether it's visually selected.

Comment: @Herbert: thanks for the confirmation. *EDIT 2* came to mind only after I have tested the function. Maybe the function approach is helpful for a more sophisticated requirement, so I leave it there, for the moment.

Comment: `@René:`Yes, your method for extracting the text in visul area could be useful in different context.

Comment: Remapping gf to edit breaks the built in resolve algorithm that vim uses. It will first search in different paths, then try to find it by adding suffixes etc. If you can live without that magic, remap it, otherwise leave it alone.

Answer (score 4):

In Command-line mode `CTRL-R` followed by register "name" inserts the contents of specified register.

Assuming you have just selected the file name, press <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>CTRL + R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> which means:

- `y` -- yank selected text into unnamed register
- `:e` + SPACE -- enter Command-line mode and start typing your `:edit` command
- `CTRL-R"` -- insert just yanked text

See `:help c_CTRL-R`, `:help registers`.

BTW, `CTRL-R` does the same in insert mode too, I do use it often. See `:help i_CTRL_R`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you selected the filename while in visual mode:

1. Yank the selected filename by pressing `y`
2. Bring up the command window by pressing `q:` while still in normal mode
3. Press `i` to go into insert mode inside the command window and type `e`
4. `Esc`ape into normal mode and press `p` to paste the yanked filename
5. Press Enter

Of course if you need to do this often, you should create a macro and map it to some easy to remember key combination.

Answer (score 1):

Most often, you'll want to just yank a valid filename from around the current cursor position. Vim has a feature to detect plausible/valid filenames (`isfname`) and you can use it without selecting anything, typing <kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd>

Alternatively there is <kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>C-w</kbd> for the currently selected word.

As mentioned by others you can also refer to any register using <kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>`<reg>`</kbd> (so e.g. <kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> for the default register)